# Determine if number is prime example in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm practicing python.  Trying to write a simple program to determine if a number is prime or not.  In my code the number 2 shows no results and 9 is said to be prime...agh!  I'm clearly missing some logic here...what am I doing wrong.

---

```
num = int(input("number? "))

if num > 1:
    for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i)==0:
            print(num, "Not Prime")
            break
        else:
            print(num, "Is Prime")
            break
else:
    print(num, "is never prime")
```

Comment: You're `break`ing from the loop on the first iteration of the loop no matter what. `i` will only ever be `2`, so this code is really just checking if a number is even or odd.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having is that you break out of the loop on your first iteration without actually going through the full range of `i` to `num`. You're essentially just testing if `num % 2 = 0` or not.

Try this instead:

```
import math

num = int(input("number? "))

if num > 1:
    for i in range(2, math.sqrt(num)):
        # Run through all the numbers until we encounter a case where
        # num is divisible by i or we have gone through all possibilities.
        if (num % i)==0:
            prime = false
            break
        else:
            prime = true

    # Here we print the result.
    # This is outside the loop to prevent it from being printed each iteration.
    if prime:
        print(num, "Is Prime")
    else:
        print(num, "Is not Prime")

else:
    print(num, "is never prime")
```

Comment: Thank you K-Log and Jim Lewis, both answers helped me to understand my errors more completely.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a bit off in a couple of places.

1)  You have `break` statements in both branches of the `if` statement, so you're only testing for divisibility by 2.  Once you find a divisor, you're done (you know the number is composite), but if not, you need to keep checking.

2)  `num % num` will always equal 0.  You only need to check possible divisors up to `sqrt(num)`.